# Convex envelope algorithm of random set of points

Tags: c#, linq, computational-geometry

This is my "naive" implementation of a convex hull algorithm. By naive I mean that I am not using any of the advanced [algorithms](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjUm9rq4KnKAhXHWx4KHVzoCfEQFggkMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FConvex_hull_algorithms&usg=AFQjCNHMWzGcTc7zMNhQOoOSQWRjCft3hg&sig2=8sq-Q8WFzdcXrrbKK0F01Q&bvm=bv.111677986,d.ZWU) that exist to solve this problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO
{
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Point> GetConvexEnvelope(this IEnumerable<Point> points)
        {
            if (points == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("points");

            var pointsList = points.ToList();

            if (pointsList.Count < 4)
                return pointsList;

            var envelope = new Stack<Point>();

            //Any point with minimum X is, by definition, part of the envelope so we pick the first one we find.
            envelope.Push(pointsList.OrderBy(p => p.X).First());


            //Two valid consecutive envelope points will define a ray that has all remaining points of the set on only one side or are collinear.
            //We find new envelope points simply checking rays from last identified envelope point to remaining non envelope points.
            //We add the first valid ray's end point to the envelope and continue from there.
            //Ordering valid rays by length is necessary to avoid skipping collinear envelope points. Cost should be low as typically collinear points will be scarce.
            //If no valid ray is found we are done.
            while (true)
            {
                var rays = (from ray in
                                (from second in pointsList.Except(envelope)
                                 select new Ray(envelope.Peek(), second))
                            let possibleEndPoints = pointsList.Except(new Point[] { ray.Start, ray.End })
                            where possibleEndPoints.All(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) >= 0) ||
                                  possibleEndPoints.All(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) <= 0)
                            select ray).OrderBy(r => r.LengthSquared).ToList();

                if (rays.Count > 0)
                {
                    envelope.Push(rays[0].End);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return envelope;
        }

        private struct Ray
        {
            private readonly double slope;

            public Point Start { get; private set; }
            public Point End { get; private set; }
            public double LengthSquared { get { return Math.Pow(End.Y - Start.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(End.X - Start.X, 2); } } //No need evaluating true length for ordering purposes.

            public Ray(Point start, Point end)
                : this()
            {
                Debug.Assert(end != start, "Specified points must not be equal.");

                Start = start;
                End = end;
                slope = (double)(End.Y - Start.Y) / (End.X - Start.X);
            }

            public int GetProjectionSign(Point p)
            {
                return Start.X == End.X ? Math.Sign(p.X - Start.X) : Math.Sign(p.Y - Start.Y - slope * (p.X - Start.X));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without changing the nature of the algorithm, I'd appreciate any optimizations in the code. I am pretty new to `System.Linq` and I'm not sure of all the performance implications when using language integrated queries so any guidelines or advice will be greatly appreciated.

I do not have any performance goals in mind. I'm mainly interested in optimizing the code and learn in the process.

Here is a quickly built windows forms to visually test the algorithm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        public Main(Func<Rectangle, IEnumerable<Point>> randomPointCollectionCreator)
        {
            Debug.Assert(randomPointCollectionCreator!=null);
            InitializeComponent();
            pointCollectionCreator = randomPointCollectionCreator;
        }

        private readonly Func<Rectangle, IEnumerable<Point>> pointCollectionCreator;
        private IEnumerable<Point> points;
        private Point[] envelope; 

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (points != null)
            {
                using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
                {
                    foreach (var point in points)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, point.X - 2, point.Y - 2, 4, 4);
                    }

                    if (envelope != null)
                    {
                        var path = new GraphicsPath();
                        path.AddLines(envelope);
                        path.CloseFigure();
                        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void Main_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bounds = ClientRectangle;
            bounds.Inflate(-50, -50);
            points = pointCollectionCreator(bounds);
            envelope = points.GetConvexEnvelope().ToArray();
            this.Invalidate(this.ClientRectangle);
        }       
    }

    partial class Main
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Main
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(780, 558);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.Name = "Main";
            this.Text = "Main";
            this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Main_Click);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And to start it up:

```
namespace SO
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Func<Rectangle, IEnumerable<Point>> pointCreator =
                (Rectangle bounds) =>
                {
                    int counter = 0;
                    int maxCounter = 600;

                    var r = new Random();
                    var points = new List<Point>(maxCounter);
                    int rangeX = bounds.Right - bounds.Left;
                    int rangeY = bounds.Bottom - bounds.Top;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (counter == maxCounter)
                            return points;

                        points.Add(new Point(bounds.Left + r.Next(0, rangeX + 1), bounds.Top + r.Next(0, rangeY + 1)));
                        counter++;
                    }
                };

            var main = new Main(pointCreator);
            main.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>             var pointsList = points.ToList();
> ```

What is `pointsList` used for? I see:

> ```
>             if (pointsList.Count < 4)
>                 return pointsList;
> ```

> ```
>             envelope.Push(pointsList.OrderBy(p => p.X).First());
> ```

> ```
>                                 (from second in pointsList.Except(envelope)
>                                  select new Ray(envelope.Peek(), second))
>                             let possibleEndPoints = pointsList.Except(new Point[] { ray.Start, ray.End })
> ```

In my opinion it shouldn't be a list at all, but an `ISet<Point>` from which the main loop removes used points. In the worst case that would be a significant performance improvement over the first `pointsList.Except`. A small subtlety would be in the sign test, which would then have to use `points` instead of `possibleEndPoints`.

---

> ```
>             //Any point with minimum X is, by definition, part of the envelope so we pick the first one we find.
>             envelope.Push(pointsList.OrderBy(p => p.X).First());
> ```

Yes-ish. The main loop takes into account collinear points: it wouldn't be too hard to do so here as well.

---

> ```
>                 var rays = (from ray in
>                                 (from second in pointsList.Except(envelope)
>                                  select new Ray(envelope.Peek(), second))
>                             let possibleEndPoints = pointsList.Except(new Point[] { ray.Start, ray.End })
>                             where possibleEndPoints.All(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) >= 0) ||
>                                   possibleEndPoints.All(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) <= 0)
>                             select ray).OrderBy(r => r.LengthSquared).ToList();
>
>                 if (rays.Count > 0)
>                 {
>                     envelope.Push(rays[0].End);
>                 }
>                 else
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
> ```

Why call `ToList()`? Here it probably doesn't make much difference, because `OrderBy` is greedy, but in general it's better Linq style to use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` rather than `ToList()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a definitive answer but reading your code, the following comes to mind :

I bet that Math.Pow(x,2) is less efficient than x * x ...

> public double LengthSquared { get { return Math.Pow(End.Y - Start.Y,
>   2) + Math.Pow(End.X - Start.X, 2); } }

and regarding

> possibleEndPoints.All(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) >= 0) ||
>                                     possibleEndPoints.All(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) <= 0)

I suggest to invert the conditions to something like

```
.Any(p => ray.GetProjectionSign(p) >0) &&  ...
```

Checking for one item to fullfill a condition should be faster than checking for all items.

Hope this helps !